# Figure out if number is a minus or a positive number

Tags: javascript

Say I have a range which consists of `< -10` and I split this up using a regex call which leaves me with `<` `-10`.

I then have a function which gets me the number from the split and I call it like `range1.getMin()`, this would return `-10` but when I use `range1.getMin().indexOf('-')` it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your code and elaborate on what happens when it "doesn't work". Note in passing that you could parse that string into a number and compare the result against zero, which can be more robust depending on your input.

Comment: Probably your function returns a number, just compare it to `0`.

Comment: Why would you use a regular expression for a mathematical function?

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing to zero:

```
var isNegative = range1.getMin() < 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isMin(value) {
  if(value<0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

You could add a check like `eval()` for the value to make sure you're dealing with an integer.

Also, if you need to make sure you have a positive number (or negative number for that matter) before you use the number in your process, you can `Math.abs()` your number to make sure it's always a positive number.

Comment: In most cases you don't need `eval`, and you should not use it. With `eval` you always have the problem that you most likely would break _code validation_  and _code optimization_.

Comment: I agree, you could also use `parseInt()` to make sure you're dealing with numbers instead of strings that will not be compared to an integer.

Answer (score -1):

```
var val = parseInt("-10", 10)
```

can be used to parse integer and to test for positive number

```
val >= 0
```

Comment: Do not forget the redix part.. `parseInt("-10",10)`

Comment: @Pranav thanks... Down voter please explain..

Comment: I did not down Voted for sure.. :)